# Show that $\mathbb E X_n V_n \to \mathbb E XV$.

Tags: probability-theory

**(Cinlar, probability and stochastic process) If $X_n \to X$ in $L^1$, and $V_n \to V$ in $L^1$, and $(V_n)$ is a bounded sequence, then $\mathbb E X_n V_n \to \mathbb E XV$. Show.**

$$|\mathbb EX_nV_n - \mathbb EXV| \le \mathbb E|X_n-X||V_n| + \mathbb E|V_n-V||X|.$$
The first term on r.h.s. is less than equal to $b \mathbb E|X_n-X|$ for some $b$ since $|V_n|$ is bounded. Then, this converges to $0$ by $L^1$ convergence.  But, we cannot do this for the second term, right? because $X \in L^1$, but we don't know it is bounded. How can we deal with the second term?

Comment: Sorry i forgot Hölders inequality doenst work in this case :D my answer is incorrect hence i deleted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We suppose $|V_n|\leq C,\,\forall n$.
$$\begin{aligned}E[|X_nV_n-XV|]&=E[|X_nV_n-XV_n+XV_n-XV|]\leq\\
&\leq E[|V_n||X_n-X|]+E[|X||V-V_n|]\leq\\
&\leq CE[|X_n-X|]+E[|X||V-V_n|]\end{aligned}$$
Also, for $N>0$
$$\begin{aligned}E[|X||V-V_n|]&\leq E[|X|\mathbf{1}_{\{|X|>N\}}|V-V_n|]+NE[|V-V_n|]\end{aligned}$$
Now recall that $L^1$ convergence implies convergence in probability. Thus
$$P(|V|>2C)\leq P(|V_n-V|>C)+\underbrace{P(|V_n|>C)}_{=0,\,\forall n}\to 0$$
So $|V|$ is essentially bounded by $2C$. Therefore
$$E[|X|\mathbf{1}_{\{|X|>N\}}|V-V_n|]\leq 3CE[|X|\mathbf{1}_{\{|X|>N\}}]$$
and, since $X \in L^1\implies P(|X|=\infty)=0$
$$\limsup_{n \to \infty}E[|X_nV_n-XV|]\leq 3CE[|X|\mathbf{1}_{\{|X|>N\}}]\stackrel{N\to \infty,\textrm{ DCT}}{\to} 0$$